# Cause to return null values when calling a function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a function that extracts from my table, any employee name that begins with J

```
delimiter $$
create function myfunction(nume_persoane varchar (30)) returns int deterministic
begin
declare omcucap int;
select first_name into omcucap  from employee where id = nume_persoane and first_name = 'J%';
return omcucap;
end $$
```

When I call the function `select myfunction(first_name) from employee;` it returns `null`. Why is that?  What is the explication..

Answer (score 1):

```
omcucap int;
```

Is your `first_name` is an int type? I don't think so.

And consider the following change

```
UPPER(first_name) LIKE 'J%';
```

you can't use = for '%'

Comment: my first_name is varchar ..but i don't know if i called write..and if i declare corectly ..pls give me me full corect syntax

Answer (score 0):

To complete  shazin answer, to make it work, you propably need to declare omcucap as varchar.

```
declare omcucap varchar(first_name size);
```

And I don't think id is varchar. So nume_persoane would be `int(id size)` instead. And the return type would be `varchar(first_name size)`

You function will be

```
delimiter $$
create function myfunction(nume_persoane int(10)) returns varchar(50) deterministic
begin
declare omcucap varchar(50);
select first_name into omcucap  from employee where id = nume_persoane and first_name LIKE 'J%' LIMIT 1;
return omcucap;
end $$
```

Where 50 is you `first_name` size and `10` is your id size.
I add `LIMIT 1` statement to avoid few results issue.

**EDIT**
If you wan't a default value, used :

```
select IFNULL(first_name, 'default_value') into omcucap[...]
```

Comment: how can i call this function to get the corect result?

Comment: `CALL myfunction(12)` where 12 is the searching ID.

Comment: Or `SELECT myfunction(12)` where 12 is the searching ID.

Comment: it returns me null with 'select myfunction(12)'..why?

Comment: my first_name column has 14 values

Comment: Do you add LIMIT 1 as in my answer? ? Or CONCAT... if you wan't to get all values with a separator (in this case, don't forget to change the varchar size of the varaible and the return definition)

Comment: i add limit 1 but the result is still null..my id that have letter with 'J' is id 3 and 8  when i called with select myfunction(8) or (3) it returns me good result 'James' or ' Jason' but why? becouse i assume that i don't know the id that have the corect answer and my function normaly have to search from all values of the column..

Comment: Ok, so null is when you haven't result. Because the given ID isn't referring to a "J%" first_name.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter 'nume_persoane' is set to the id of the employee

> select first_name into omcucap  from employee where id = nume_persoane and first_name = 'J%';

but you calls your function with the first_name

> select myfunction(first_name)

and also the first_name is not are int or? But you try to insert the first_name to the declared variable

> declare omcucap int; 
> select first_name into omcucap ...

#### UPDATE

Use these function :

```
delimiter $$
create function myfunction(p1 int) returns int
begin
declare eID int;
select id into eID  from employee where id = p1 and first_name LIKE 'J%';
return eID;
end $$
```

and executed the function with these select statement:

```
SELECT myfunction(id) FROM employee;
```

Comment: first_name is the column name from table;

Comment: first_name is the column name from table

Comment: yes i knowm but you call your function with select 'myfunction(first_name)' and your function is declared 'create function myfunction(nume_persoane varchar (30)) ' and the parameter is used in the function with 'where id = nume_persoane' so never a id with the same value with the first_name will be exists right?

Comment: but how can i call this function corectly?

Comment: is the function necessary ? are cant use a select like this ? select first_name from employee where first_name = 'J%';

Comment: my id that have letter with 'J' is id 3 and 8

Comment: so i have to call my function with this ...select myfunction(3) or (8) to get the corect result?

Comment: could be possible try it... but set the parameter from the function to int

Comment: my id that have letter with 'J' is id 3 and 8 when i called with select myfunction(8) or (3) it returns me good result 'James' or ' Jason' but why? becouse i assume that i don't know the id that have the corect answer and my function normaly have to search from all values of the column..

Comment: i assume that function can return only one result set and if you try to call the function in a select query with more id's the result is null

Comment: i understand but how can i call my function when i dont know that    id 8 return my corect result 'james'

Comment: select myfunction(?)...to return me 'James'

Comment: I'm interested in the function to search from all values of column first_name and return me corect answer

Comment: delimiter $$
create function myfunction(p1 int) returns int
begin
declare eID int;
select id into eID  from employee where id = p1 and first_name = 'J%';
return eID;
end $$

Comment: and with these select myfunction(id) from employee;

Comment: man your function is create ok but when i called it returns me null for 13 fields..

Comment: my id column has not unique values...column id has 1,2,5,6,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 values

Comment: oh im sorry please use LIKE in the function not equal, why is your id not unique?

Comment: with like when a call the function give and error like this..result consisted of more that one row

Comment: please set your id to an primary key and use the innodb as mysql engine so it will work